# How can I override CSS?

Tags: html, css

In the following example

http://jsfiddle.net/xBRPg/

I'm trying to create a yellow background for one of my table rows. The following line of code

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
```

Seems to supersede my own styling. If I remove the classes the row appears yellow as desired. Is there some way to maintain the classes yet override the setting so that my colour takes top priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because of CSS specificity - `table.table-striped tr` is more specific than `table tr`. More specific rules override less specific ones. In my opinion you should avoid `!important` as long as possible, and instead focus on making your selectors more specific. So in your case, make that:

```
table.table-striped tr.zebraHover td {
    background-color: #FFFACD;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The row **is** yellow. It is just that the cells inside it are #f9f9f9 so you can't see the row's background colour through them.

You need to change your selector to match the cells in the row, and not the row itself. You will also need to increase the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) of the selector as the ones being used already are more specific then you have.

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your css

```
tr.zebraHover td {
            background-color: #FFFACD !important;
}
```

And yes I know it is very dirty. If someone knows this better, comment on my answer. I'd rely like to know a better solution!

Comment: He shouldn't need to use !important. The issue here is selector precedence. He just needs a selector with a higher value, or equal defined later.

Comment: Thanks, I found another answer thanks to you. Changed the class to an id so that it was more specific than a class. Works like a charm thanks

Comment: That is why I added that I know it is a very dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class to an id.

CSS:

```
#zebraHover td{
            background-color: #FFFACD;
        }
```

HTML

```
<tr id="zebraHover">
     <td>1</td>
     <td>User1</td>
     <td>user1@gmail.com</td>
     <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Deactivate</a></td>
 </tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBRPg/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the rule that set alternating background colors for rows using selectors with high specificity. To suitably override them, use e.g.

```
    tr.zebraHover,
    .table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1).zebraHover td
    {
        background-color: #FFFACD;
    }
```